# Jmeter: Sequential and Parallel execution

Tags: multithreading, jmeter, sequential, parallel-execution

I want to run the login thread group always first and wait for it to finish. And then in the same test plan run other thread group in parallel.

e.g.
Login-1 (always first )
Thread group-2 (after login in parallel)
Thread group-3 (after login in parallel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [setUp Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#setUp_Thread_Group), as per description:

> A special type of ThreadGroup that can be utilized to perform Pre-Test Actions. The behavior of these threads is exactly like a normal Thread Group element. The difference is **that these type of threads execute before the test proceeds to the executing of regular Thread Groups**.

More information: [How to Use the SetUp Thread Group in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/thread-group-jmeter)

Answer (score 1):

Below Test plan might help you.
[image]

- Here first thread group is a setUP Thread Group which will be executed once, Rest are regular thread groups.
  (You can run setUp Thread group with as many number of users and duration you want, other Regular Thread groups will wait until setup thread is completed)
- On test plan level uncheck "Run Thread Groups consecutively"